# Is there a way to allow the user to manage his data with a REST API call in Keycloak?

Tags: next.js, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

The aim is to have a Spring resource server and a Next.js client (with next-auth). Going to the user's profile, the user can edit his username, password etc.

Is there a way for the user to use the client to send an API call to change these things? Or is navigating to the Keycloak user management the only way to implement that?

Comment: No, what are the endpoints (if there are any) to manage my Keycloak user data. Instead of navigating to the panel provided by Keycloak.

Comment: What version of Keycloak do you use?

Comment: Did you try https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.1.1/rest-api/index.html